# How on Earth to get BlackBerry 10 up and running

Tags: blackberry-10

I have now spent the whole day attempting to try and simply run a Hello World application on the blackberry 10 simulator. I have now done the following:

1. Downloaded Webworks and the Simulator and installed them both.
2. I have now created a Blackberry ID. I get a bbidtoken.csk file. I have placed this in the AppData/Local/Research In Motion folder.
3. I have then created the author.p12 file using the blackberry-keytool.
4. I have followed everything perfectly in the guides! When I build the project it complained about a debugtoken (Something that we are never told to do in the guides!!!)
5. I have then used the following:

[image]

The yellow star is my password. Frankly I've got no clue why I'm getting this error. I dont know what to do anymore?? I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Please can anyone help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about BB but will take a guess.  You are working inside c:\program files\ which is pretty much always a bad place to put your code.  By default, only apps running "as admin" can write to it.  Try running the command window as admin or, better yet, do your dev work in a more appropriate folder

Comment: Firstly Rob, you are a genius! Secondly I wasn't saving my code their. That's where the webworks sdk installed it's self. Hence why I was working out of Program Files. But THANK YOU SO MUCH!